# Surface Pro Wifi Issues on Mint KDE 17

Tags: linux, linux-mint, wifi, surface

I'm running Mint 17 KDE on the Surface Pro 1. Wifi worked on installation, however, after about an hour of use the internet stops working and will not reconnect to any wifi. I have to shut the computer off to fix it, but then it stops working again in about an hour.

I've updated the kernel to the latest Ubuntu 3.17 utopic kernel. No change in wifi.

Any ideas?

The dmesg results are 5 miles long. One thing that keeps repeating though:

```
[ 2881.370943] usb 3-3: PREP_CMD: FW is in bad state
[ 2881.370944] usb 3-3: failed to get signal information
[ 2887.154904] usb 3-3: 4295613744 : Tx timeout(#96), bss_type-num = 0-0
[ 2887.368282] usb 3-3: PREP_CMD: FW is in bad state
[ 2887.368286] usb 3-3: failed to get signal information
[ 2887.368299] usb 3-3: PREP_CMD: FW is in bad state
[ 2887.368301] usb 3-3: failed to get signal information
[ 2893.376170] usb 3-3: PREP_CMD: FW is in bad state
[ 2893.376176] usb 3-3: failed to get signal information
[ 2893.376197] usb 3-3: PREP_CMD: FW is in bad state
[ 2893.376199] usb 3-3: failed to get signal information
[ 2897.159269] usb 3-3: 4295616244 : Tx timeout(#97), bss_type-num = 0-0
```

This page has some sort of "patch" in it. http://marc.info/?l=linux-wireless&m=140425083601658&w=4 I don't know what any of this means. How do I fix my kernel driver with that link?

Comment: You're running Linux Mint and installed an Ubuntu kernel? That is probably not a good idea.

Comment: You can find system errors by running `dmesg` in the terminal.  Try running that command after your wifi stops working and look for (and post here) errors related to wifi near the bottom of the output.

Comment: @drs I have posted the dmesg above (a small portion of the same thing repeating over and over again).

Comment: This may a known issue with running Linux on MS Surface Pro 1. See [this Linux kernel bug report](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=69661).

Comment: @drs That link has a patch http://marc.info/?l=linux-wireless&m=140425083601658&w=4 how do I apply whats in that text to my kernel driver?

Comment: That sounds like a good, second question to ask.