# Surface Pro Compatible Wireless cards and drivers

Tags: kernel, wifi, surface

In reference to this post:

[Surface Pro Wifi Issues on Mint KDE 17](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158262/surface-pro-wifi-issues-on-mint-kde-17)

there doesn't seem to be any solution to fixing the wifi issues on the Surface Pro when running Linux. The Marvell card doesn't even function properly under high traffic in Windows.

Anyone know of a good wireless hardware replacement that will fit in the Surface Pro and are drivers available for in the latest linux kernel?

Comment: did you ever resolve this? I have Surface Pro also running Arch. There have been a lot of bug reports on this. Just looking for a soluton. I am assuming you have the wifi drop connection issue?

Comment: @David Haven't found anything. I've updated to the latest kernel and that hasn't fixed the wifi issue. I've been connecting a USB internet adapter at the moment.

Comment: yeah, i have the latest kernel also. If I find an answer I will link you to it, if you could do the same I would **forever** greatful. this is rather annoying. I wonder if there is a way to bring the wifi back without rebooting. Unfortunately for me, I don't have a wifi dongle.

Answer (score 1):

Having the same issue here, went to install Arch on my surface pro but would crash every time I tried to run the pacstrap, I also had an issue with not being able to boot from my SD card, simply wouldn't read it till it was fully booted so I have to boot from a USB.  I ended up using using an SD card as a mirror image, mirroring the partition sizes on both and installed ran the pacstrap and installed dosfstools and then used clonezilla to clone both the boot and root partitions to the hard drive and finished configuring on the surface.   It was a nightmare but I have it working now.  Now I can use a USB wifi stick to get a wireless connection that doesn't crash the system.  Really hoping a driver gets released for this at some point.  Note: Don't take any shortcuts before doing the pacstrap command.  If the boot partition doesn't get mounted before this the Kernel version doesn't get written to the boot partition.  There may be a few packages that need to be installed to the image before cloning over to ensure you can configure your USB stick.